# JavaFX WebView throwing an Exception

Tags: java, javascript, webview

I am using JavaFX WebView as a "chat container", for messages.

Everytime a new message comes up, I call:

```
engine.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

(I also have an if-check, so I don't execute the line if the user has scrolled up)

However, this line appears to cause an exception every time that the scrollbar isn't visible, because the scrollbar is apparently lazily initialized.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.getThumb(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.thumbPosition(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:284)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.getThumbPosition(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1427)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:948)
```

I tried to add another if-check in JavaScript: `document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;` but it didn't fix the issue.

Anyone have ideas how to get rid of the exception (besides filing a bug report :)?

Comment: That moment, when you find a question on SO with exactly the same problem but no answer... Interestingly, this worked before I re-layouted my application so it might have to do something with the layouting.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

```
if (scene != null
    && scene.getWindow() != null
        && scene.getWindow().isShowing()) {
  engine.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
}
```

## Long(er) answer

It fails because the WebView's ScrollBar's skin has not been set. To avoid that,

- the WebView must be attached to a Scene
- the Scene must be attached to a Window
- the Window must have been displayed at least once

OR, more specific:

- the WebView must be attached to a Scene
- `WebView.applyCss()` must have been called

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144162) which unfortunately has been closed unfixed.

I submitted a new bug report (because it's not possible to comment on existing ones -.-) and sent them [an example to reproduce it](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144162).